# site move in Google WebMaster Tool

Tags: domains, google-search-console

I have recently moved my website to a new domain name.

The old domain is 301 to the new domain, and I have followed all the procedure to inform Google about the domain change, using WebMaster Tool.

It's been almost a week and the new domain only has 1 page indexed. The old domain still has hundreds of pages indexed.

Is this normal and how long should I expect the new domain to be indexed in place of the old one  ?

Comment: Be patient. Search engines are notoriously slow- think about it, you are concerned about one site and they are concerned about all the sites on the internet- it just plain takes time to index the site on the internet. It is not a fast process.

Comment: Takes much longer than a week. Normally 2-6 weeks minimal.

Answer (score 2):

There's a programmed delay just so that they make sure that tests run against the system are inconclusive. For that very reason, delay's' length is not always the same. So, you'll have to simply wait.

Comment: I understand. However I have also noticed that Google started indexing my pages on the new domain, which is great (although they still don't appear in GWM Tool). But the same pages on the old domain are still indexed (and they actually rank higher). I though the idea what that Google would remove the old domain and replace it with the new one. Instead it is currently indexing both. Or is it just temporary ?

Comment: If they are 301'd, they won't stay indexed for very long.

Comment: Even if you set 301s correctly and do a change of address in search console the old URLs can stay indexed for a very long time.  Example, seomoz.com re branded to moz.com in March, 2013, yet there are still semoz.com URLS indexed and you can bet they did the domains switch correctly:  https://goo.gl/s4kxUr

Comment: Sure, always exceptions, buth that's what - less then 0,01% of all their urls?